# Remove whatever is after a character but exist the same character

Tags: r

In a dataframe like this one:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4), text = c("word1","word2","word3","word4"), ts = c("something1,here,other","something2,here,other","something5,here,other","something4,here,other")
```

I would like to keep only what exist before the first comma in column ts and remove whatever if after it. Like this result:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4), text = c("word1","word2","word3","word4"), ts = c("something1","something2","something5","something4")
```

I tried this but it doesn't suite:

```
df$ts <- gsub(",","",df$ts)
```

How can I procide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close...
Use `,.*` as pattern, to replace the comma **and** everything after that first comma (that would be the `.*`-part).

```
df$ts <- gsub( ",.*", "", df$ts )

#   id  text         ts
# 1  1 word1 something1
# 2  2 word2 something2
# 3  3 word3 something5
# 4  4 word4 something4
```

read more about regex: http://stat545.com/block022_regular-expression.html